# sql left join causing records to not pulling from second table

Tags: sql, left-join

I have three tables, `invoice i`, `trans t`, and `arnotes a`.  All three tables have a column of `reference_num`.  Records will exist in `i`, `t`, and sometimes `a`.  I want to pull all the records in `i` and `t`, and if it has a record in `a`, then show the data from column `reason`.

In addition, I only want DISTINCT results.  I currently have the following, but it is only returning records that exist in all three.  If there is no record in a, it's not pulling the record from `i` and `t` and showing a null for `reason`, the record isn't being pulled at all.  Any assistance please?

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.BT_ID,
    i.ST_ID,
    i.REFERENCE_NUM,
    i.INVOICE_DATE,
    i.BALANCE,
    t.GL_ACCOUNT,
    a.REASON
FROM Invoice i
INNER JOIN Trans t ON i.REFERENCE_NUM = t.INVOICE_REFERENCE_NUM
LEFT OUTER JOIN ARNOTES a ON t.INVOICE_REFERENCE_NUM = a.INVOICE_NUM
WHERE (i.BALANCE > 0)
    AND (t.GL_ACCOUNT <> '')
    AND (t.TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'dist')
    AND (NOT (a.REASON LIKE '%COLLECTIONS%'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `not a.REASON like '%COLLECTIONS%'` is turning the `left join` into an inner join. Move it to the `ON` clause like this:

```
select distinct i.BT_ID,
    i.ST_ID,
    i.REFERENCE_NUM,
    i.INVOICE_DATE,
    i.BALANCE,
    t.GL_ACCOUNT,
    a.REASON
from Invoice i
inner join Trans t on i.REFERENCE_NUM = t.INVOICE_REFERENCE_NUM
left outer join ARNOTES a on t.INVOICE_REFERENCE_NUM = a.INVOICE_NUM
    and a.REASON not like '%COLLECTIONS%'
where i.BALANCE > 0
    and t.GL_ACCOUNT <> ''
    and t.TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'dist'
```

Comment: ah hah!  That did it.  Thank you!